# Adding annotations for the bar chart in Plotly R

Tags: r, annotations, plotly, bar-chart

I need to add annotations to the chart for 2019 and 2020. I have a problem to get to 2020. I wanted to do it as shown below, but the text overlaps with the text of 2019.

[image]

```
quarter <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
y_18 <- c(10, 16, 23)
y_19 <- c(12, 20, 29)
y_20 <- c(14, NA, NA)
TD <- data.frame(quarter, y_18, y_19, y_20)

fig <- plot_ly(TD, x = ~quarter, y = ~y_18, type = 'bar', name = '2018')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~y_19, name = '2019')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~y_20, name = '2020')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'count'), barmode = 'group')
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations( x = TD$quarter,
                                y = TD$y_19,
                                text = c("+2","+4","+6"),
                                xref = "x",
                                yref = "y",
                                showarrow = TRUE)
```

```
#my solutions:
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations( x = TD[1,1],
                                y = TD[1,3],
                                text = "+2",
                                xref = "x",
                                yref = "y",
                                showarrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little manual intervention, you can figure out suitable y coordinates (see below).
I left in all 3 coordinates, so if you want to label the ones with NA, just replace the blank annotations and the showarrow FALSE logicals in the code:

```r
library(plotly)
quarter <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3")
y_18 <- c(10, 16, 23)
y_19 <- c(12, 20, 29)
y_20 <- c(14, NA, NA)
TD <- data.frame(quarter, y_18, y_19, y_20)

fig <- plot_ly(TD, x = ~quarter, y = ~y_18, type = 'bar', name = '2018')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~y_19, name = '2019')
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~y_20, name = '2020')
fig <- fig %>% layout(yaxis = list(title = 'count'), barmode = 'group')
fig <- fig %>% add_annotations( x = TD$quarter,
                                y = TD$y_19,
                                text = c("+2","+4","+6"),
                                xref = "x",
                                yref = "y",
                                showarrow = TRUE)

fig %>% add_annotations( x = c(.25, 1.25, 2.25),
                         y = TD$y_20,
                         text = c("+2","",""),
                         xref = "x",
                         yref = "y",
                         showarrow = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why such values for x?

Comment: Honestly, I just used trial and error here. There might be a hidden logic in there (like the index of the groups being 0,1,2, and an offset from the center of the group, maybe), but I have seen no documentation of that.